# How to create an IronPython file that simply returns a single value to C#?

Tags: c#, dynamic, interop, ironpython

I'm trying to create a configuration file for a C# app in IronPython.  Is there any way I can have that python file just return a value, or do I have to go through variables/functions to access the results of the script?

i.e., right now I've got Config.py that looks like

`x = "test"`

and C# code that goes

`dynamic pyfile = Python.CreateRuntime().ExecuteFile("Config.py");
                Console.WriteLine(pyfile.x);`

Is there any way to remove the x?

Comment: Are you really proposing to put a single configuration value into a single py file?  You will have dozens of py files if you do that.  Doesn't it make more sense to just have one py file to hold all of your configuration values?

Comment: Perhaps if you share your actual problem, we can suggest solutions. Certainly your problem can not really be having to type two extra characters...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a ScriptSource with SourceCodeKind.AutoDetect and it will return the last expression in the file.